# Spring boot Jar cannot work in Debian 8.1 via /etc/init.d/myapp, But work in CentOS

Tags: spring, spring-boot, debian

I use the spring-boot-starter, my pom is:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
                <layout>ZIP</layout>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

when I execute service myapp start, the message shown:

```
/etc/init.d/weacar: 2: /etc/init.d/weacar: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
```

But it's ok In CentOS, Why this happen? Is it bug of Spring-boot?

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't you post your entire POM so users can have a better idea.

Comment: Are you sure that it's OK on CentOS? You haven't told Spring Boot's maven plugin to generate a jar that's fully executable (http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#deployment-install) so I'd expect it to fail irrespective of OS. Also, what version of Spring Boot are you using?

Comment: Looks more like a bug (incompatibility) of your init script. Please post this as well.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error when I was trying to start a regular/fat boot jar accidentally using this approach. I had changed my build.xml to create an executable jar, but I had not updated the /var folder on the Linux machine with the new executable jar. Once I did a 'mvn clean package', and then copied the resulting new executable jar to the Linux machine I was trying this on, 'service  start' worked as expected. ﻿